# How To Create Footer Menu Location For The Latest 2024 Cirkle Theme

Tags: menus, footer

The theme that I am working with is Cirkle Theme. I am not a coder and with very limited tech experience with wordpress site building.
I created footer 1 and footer 2 Menus but there is no footer location to add the created menu.
I tried using widget but that too did not work because I could not find the created footer 1 and footer 2 menus in the widget arear to add them to the footer widget. .
I went to appearance -customize but could not create a footer location. Do not know how to.
There's also message that said that Cirkle theme only has room for two menu location, main and side.
This theme already has Categories and Achieve in the footer, they are empty.
How do I add two created menus to the footer. i cannot code. I have added Gutenberg editor to the theme. The theme came with elementor that I have disabled.

Comment: You have to ask this question of the Cirkle Theme developers/support.  As it's a third-party theme there's very little likelihood that someone here will know the answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To add your custom menus (Footer 1 and Footer 2) to the footer in your WordPress site using the Cirkle Theme, especially when you have limited coding experience, you can follow these steps. Since the Cirkle Theme only has two menu locations by default (main and side), and you've disabled Elementor in favor of Gutenberg, you'll have to use a workaround:

**Use Gutenberg Blocks:**
Since you've added the Gutenberg editor, you can utilize its features to add your menus to the footer.

Edit the Footer with Gutenberg:
If your theme supports full-site editing, you might be able to directly edit the footer area. Look for an option under "Appearance" → "Editor" (Gutenberg Full Site Editing). If this option is available, you can edit the footer layout directly and add Navigation blocks for your menus.

**Custom HTML Block:**
If direct editing is not available, you can use a Custom HTML block in a post or page to display your menus. You would manually link your menu items using HTML. This is less ideal as it requires updating the HTML manually if your menu changes.

**Use Widgets:**

If the theme’s footer supports widgets, you can try adding a Navigation Menu widget. Go to "Appearance" → "Widgets" and add the "Navigation Menu" widget to one of the footer widget areas.
In the Navigation Menu widget, select the menu you want to display (Footer 1 or Footer 2).
Check Theme Documentation/Support:

It's worth checking the theme’s documentation or contacting the theme support for specific instructions. They might provide a simple solution tailored for the Cirkle Theme.
Consider Re-enabling Elementor:

If you initially disabled Elementor for a specific reason, consider re-enabling it temporarily. Elementor can make it easier to edit the footer and add menus without coding.
Third-party Plugins:

You can also consider using a third-party plugin that allows for more flexibility in menu locations. Look for plugins that offer footer menu widgets or extended menu functionality.
Create a Child Theme:

This is a more advanced option and might require some coding or assistance. Creating a child theme allows you to customize the theme without losing changes on theme updates. You can then add additional menu locations with the help of a developer or using online tutorials.
Remember, while these steps can help you add menus to your footer, the exact process can vary based on the theme's specific features and limitations. If you're not comfortable with these steps, it might be worth considering hiring a developer for this task. Since you mentioned you're not a coder, ensure any changes you make are backed up, so you can revert if something goes wrong.